# Should the user id (Guid) in MVC 5 authorisation be hidden from the user?

Tags: security, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to know if there is any reason for the user id (Guid) in the standard MVC 5 authorisation system to be hidden from the user. The reason I ask is so that I can see whether to use that ID for personal user page referencing.

For example I could maybe create a profile page for the user or have posts that this user can personally edit. From what I understand it is ok to use a foreign key as a primary key in tables. Each user could have a profile page using the user id. This would mean that the user would see the user id of course:

```
public ActionResult Profile(Guid? id)
{
    //check user etc
}
```

Just as a side note. I would rather do that kind of thing than alter the authentication tables. You would obviously have to use separate tables for things like posts anyway. I am making reference to things like user details. I really do not like extending the user tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Guid id to identify and find a user for a particular task or you could use anything else that would be unique per user. Whichever you like will work. Personally I would use a user name that is unique per user just because it makes prettier URLs. But there is nothing wrong with using the Guid either it solves the puprose of providing you some piece of identifiable information to retrieve the correct user/profile record.

There could be some security issue if people know that is what you're doing, but as long as you make sure that people can't access pages they are not suppose to and always use parameters in your sql queries it should be fine.

Comment: One problem with username may be if that gets changed. This was the reason I thought it would be better to use the user id. Maybe some people do not provide for the ability to change usernames but it was something I added in for the admin only just in case someone desperately needed to change a username later down the line.

Comment: Additionally, I was just going to use an id anyway (like ProfileID). I was just wondering if it was excessive. I know scaffolding works much better if you use an autonumber or a Guid.

Comment: You could keep track of user names and automatically forward older user pages to the new ones. For simplicity's sake, using the ID doesn't hurt either.

Comment: Ok I am with you there I think. The main point about whether the user can see their user id seems to have been addressed. What I did not mention in the original question is that, even if I did use a ProfileID as the PK, the user would still see the user id as a hidden field in any forms (unless I were to  use one table solely for linking the 2 ids which is a bit messy).

Comment: I've used User IDs as a hidden field in forms before and it works just fine. I've also used User IDs as part of the URL and if I needed the user id I'd just take a look at what URL the data was posted to as well. Any of these solutions will give you want you need.